# Typo3 custom Content Elements cache problem

Tags: php, caching, typo3

In Typo3 I have my custom content elements (CEs) defined like so, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE tt_content
(
    my_rich_text_relation       int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
);

# Custom CE for displaying rich text.
CREATE TABLE tx_mythemes_rich_text
(
    uid              int(11)                      NOT NULL auto_increment,
    pid              int(11)          DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,

    text             text,
    ....
);
```

And:

```
lib.myContentElement = FLUIDTEMPLATE
lib.myContentElement {
    templateRootPaths.0 = EXT:my_themes/Resources/Private/Templates/ContentElements/
    partialRootPaths.0 = EXT:my_themes/Resources/Private/Partials/ContentElements/
    layoutRootPaths.0 = EXT:my_themes/Resources/Private/Layouts/ContentElements/
}

tt_content {
    my_rich_text >
    my_rich_text =< lib.myContentElement
    my_rich_text {
        templateName = RichText
        dataProcessing {
            330 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
            330 {
                table = tx_mythemes_rich_text
                pidInList = this
                where = uid=
                where.dataWrap = |{field:mythemes_rich_text_relation}
                as = richText
            }
        }
    }
```

This works in my local system (Docker image) but I don't know why in our beta platform (where the context is not "development" it doesn't. When I add a new custom CE and refresh the caches, it gets displayed, but as soon as something changes (e.g. I add a new CE to the page), the Template of the CE doesn't get rendered (funny thing: the Layout does get rendered).
What can be happening? This looks so much like a cache problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you also explain what `lib.myContentElement` is and why you use the reference operator instead of copy?

Comment: Table `tx_mythemes_rich_text` does not have `mythemes_rich_text_relation` field. This is the error. And two wraps there are not needed. Just use `where.dataWrap = uid={field:mythemes_rich_text_relation}`